# VMs not able to ping Virtual Gateway

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have set up Devstack with two virtual routers. One of the routers has an external IP 172.24.4.4 and an internal IP of 10.10.6.1 I have a private cloud which is in the 10.10.6.0/24 network. I have spawned a VM in this cloud whose IP is 10.10.6.3 I have also set up a floating IP: 172.24.4.5 However, I am unable to ping the floating IP. Also, noticed that I am unable to ping the VM 10.10.6.3 from the neutron. Output:

```
sudo ip netns exec qrouter-74759db2-9044-46eb-a32a-325995b88cf9 ping 10.10.6.3
PING 10.10.6.3 (10.10.6.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.6.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.6.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.6.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.6.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.10.6.3 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3998ms
pipe 3
```

I also spawned a Cirros VM and found that it is not able to ping the gatway 10.10.6.1 It worked last time around and this time, not sure what changed. ICMP security rule is also in place.

Please let me know if you need any other info. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if dhcp agent is working fine:

Get in VM and make sure IP 10.10.6.3 is on ethX.

- Check if openvswitch agent is working fine:

Gateway device owning IP 10.10.6.1 (qr-XXXX) and device linked to your VM (qvoXXXX) should in the same vlan. Use command "ovs-vsctl show” to find out vlan tag of device.

- Check security group is working fine:

Use tcpdump to capture packets of device tapXXXX and device qvoXXXX. If packet only show in device qvoXXXX and not in device tapXXXX, it's filtered by security group.